# "Down the stack"

Tags: stack, terminology

If I'm trying to find a bug that's being called lower in the call stack, that'd be "down" the stack, right?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a perfectly cromulent question.

Comment: Someone might think of it as far off to the right.

Comment: This person has been rep-inflating an account. watch out for "john"

Comment: I think some people think this question is below them.

*ba dum ch*  I'll be here all night, folks.

Comment: Looks like we got your scheme underwraps.

Comment: *Obviously* 'lower' is 'down', but what do you mean by 'lower'?

Answer (score 2):

For an upward growing stack (think plates), then yes.  Something in a stack frame lower than your current frame is said to be 'below' you (though to be honest, I don't hear people say 'down' the stack often).

EDIT: And by 'lower', I mean in a stack frame which you've stored aside in order to get to your current frame.  For instance:

```
int main() {
    a();
}

void a() {
    b();
}

int b() {
   return 0;
}
```

At the 'peak', `main()` would be the bottom frame, and on top of it would be `a()` and then `b()` at the top.

(Your comment about 'calling' a bug is also somewhat confusing.)

Comment: +1 for qualifying "an upward growing stack".  This seems to be the heart of the issue -- do you imagine the stack as growing upward or downward?  I for one always think of stacks like the stacks of papers on my desk -- they always grow upward.  (But AFAIK most OSs implement the call stack as growing downward instead, so that's a perfectly legitimate way of looking at it too...)

Answer (score 1):

Correct. "Down" the stack means inside nested function calls. If A calls B and B calls C, C is "down the stack" from A, and A is "up the stack" from C.

Additionally, one doesn't usually "call" a bug. One "encounters" or "reproduces" bugs.